# Why does rubocop recommend require: false in Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

The [rubocop readme](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#installation) says:

> If you'd rather install RuboCop using bundler, don't require it in
>   your Gemfile:
>
> `gem 'rubocop', require: false`

Why not?

On a few projects, I have had bundler require rubocop, and have not run into any problems. I also put rubocop in my `group :development, :test` block, because I don't need it in production.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a guess, but the reason why `require: false` is suggested is because RubuCop is designed to be run as a CLI and not to be loaded as part of the environment when the application is started.

If you don't set `require: false`, Rails will load the gem. Even if the gem doesn't conflict with the app process, if you don't need it then loading the library it's an unnecessary overhead (both in terms of memory and allocation).

Comment: Seems like a good guess. One thing though: "[rubocop] is designed to be run as a CLI" Yes, but it also supports rake integration, for which it must be required, no?